# SQL error with script to create

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, ssms

I used the SQL Server management studio on a table with Create Script to New and did minor changes.  Give me an error "Incorrect syntax near '('" for the "(" after "WITH"

```
/* EventType Table Creation */

CREATE TABLE [EventType]
(
 [pkEventID]  [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [BeginDate]  [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [EndDate]  [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [Comments]  [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventType] PRIMARY KEY 
 CLUSTERED 
 (
 [pkEventID] ASC
 )
 WITH 
 (
  PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
  STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
 ) 
 ON [PRIMARY]
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of Microsoft SQL Server are you executing this `CREATE TABLE` statement against?  According to documentation, MS SQL Server 2000 does not recognize the syntax for `WITH (...index options...)`.  That syntax is supported in MS SQL Server 2005 and later.

Even if you use SQL Managment Studio 2005, you may be connecting to MS SQL Server 2000.  To verify the version, try this query:

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), 
  SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), 
  SERVERPROPERTY ('edition');
```

MS SQL Server 2000's `productversion` is 8.x.

MS SQL Server 2005's `productversion` is 9.x.

MS SQL Server 2008's `productversion` is 10.x.

Comment: SQL Management Studio 2005 - again, the tool generated the code and then complained about it :)

Comment: OK, but what's the version of the MS SQL Server you're connecting to from Management Studio 2005?

Comment: The server I am accesing shows 8.0.2039 as the version which is 2000.  The fact that I am using a 2005 tool created the "Create" script without taking that in to account.  Thanks.